# Visual Studio Online with Git. Database version control considerations

Tags: azure-devops

We are going to use Visual studio Online with Git as our future source control. Our projects are asp.net web sites with SQL Server database backend.

We want to source control our databases as well into Visual Studio Online. Not the data, obviously - but the other stuff: sprocs, views, functions schemas, tables etc...

An suggestions comments concerning nice ways to do this? We are considering Visual Studio Data Tools...

Any suggestions/comments/user experiences you would like to share would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The built in data tools work but are cumbersome.

The other two legitimate options are:

-Redgate: Which works the same way as the SQL Data Tools and produces a dacpac.

-Ready Roll: Works in a more traditional way with differencing scripts

If you are looking for a free option then the SQL Data Tools are best. If you want to source control your Schema and generate upgrade scripts then you can progress to the Redgate solution from there. If you have a DBA nazi then you might be better with ready roll, or better yet, fire the dba..

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what our product (yes I work for them) DBmaestro Teamwork does.

- It enforces and keep track on the changes of structure and content
- It prevents two parallel changes on an object structure or content by
  two (as long they work on the same object - meaning, same database,
  same schema, ...)
- It uses a baseline aware analysis which understand the nature of the
  change and knows if the change should be promoted or should be
  ignored (as it was made from another environment) or if there is a
  conflict And much more…

I would encourage you to read a comprehensive, unbiased review on Database Enforced Management Solution by veteran Database expert Ben Taylor which he posted on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20140907002729-287832-solve-database-change-mangement-with-dbmaestro